# Typescript error for fetch options when given as a variable

Tags: typescript

When this code complies perfectly

```
fetch('someurl', {
    method: 'GET',
    credentials:"same-origin"
})
```

The below code gives me compilation error for fetch('someurl', init);

```
const init = {
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: "same-origin"
};

fetch('someurl', init);
```

Why is it so?

find the code [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=14&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/FAMwpgLgxgFgFAcgM4HsC2YCuAnANggGgAIBvYIiojCGFAEwC4iEBxAUQBVDzKpsw6YAHYQAlgENcSBgCIk4jAFoU2UQHNRQmcAC+ASmCGoKIUghFNo8wF5SPCtVqNm7LgXtE+A4WMnSicgpgyqoaWroA3Ibg0PDI6Fh4hBZCVnpRwEA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by type.

In the first example you initialize object of type RequestInit, but in the second it's const of type :

```
{
    method: string;
    credentials: string;
}
```

causing the problem.

To solve it set init type to RequestInit

you can see the correction [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=8&ssc=11&pln=8&pc=26#code/FAMwpgLgxgFgFAcgM4HsC2YCuAnANggGgAIBvYIiojCGFAEwC4iEBxAUQBVDzKpsw6YAHYQAlgENcSBgCIk4jAFoU2UQHNRQmcAC%20ASmCGoKIUghFNoiEwBKYAI6YwZgJJCrRALykeFarUZmdi4CXyI%20AWExSWkiOQUwZVUNLV0AbkNwaHhkdCw8Qgt3CD0M4CA)

Comment: Why typescript cannot infer the type?

Comment: It does infer it on first code example provided.

The whole premise of using typescript is restricting default javascript idea of anything being able to be anything.

The moment you create object in typescript without providing explicit type it infers the type directly from the object.